# JSONDecoder unable to decode *value/fragment* types on *Mac*

Tags: swift, macos, jsondecoder

Does anyone know of a way to configure the **Mac** version of `JSONDecoder` so that it is able to `decode` fragment/value types?

---

I am writing Swift code that needs to work on both Mac and iOS.  I am using `Decodable` with `JSONDecoder` to try and parse some JSON.  I have an enum thats `Decodable` as follows:

```
enum SomeEnum: Int, Decodable {
    case valueA = 0
    case valueB = 1
}
```

And to test the `Decodable` aspect of this I have this unit test...

```
func test_problem() {

    let jsonData = "0".data(using: .utf8)!

    let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(SomeEnum.self, from: jsonData)

    XCTAssertEqual(result, SomeEnum.valueA)
}
```

This succeeds when run against an iOS target.  HOWEVER when run against "My Mac" (which is on Mojave) an error is thrown from the `decode` call as follows:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
>   Swift.DecodingError.dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.",
>   underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
>   "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow
>   fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not
>   start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))

It seems that the iOS `JSONDecoder` is capable of decoding fragments/value types but the Mac version of `JSONDecoder` is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mojave (as well as in iOS 12) and lower you can't.

The Mac `JSONDecoder` can decode fragments in Catalina 10.15.1 and higher