# @available attribute does not work with XCTest classes or methods

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I'd like a unit test to only run on a given version of iOS or higher but the `@available` attribute does not seem to work at all with XCTest methods :-(

For example, I am not able to disable the test at all using any variation of the `@available` keyword. The test always executes regardless of whether `@available` is defined on class or function, uses `unavailable` or anything.  For example...

```
// Still runs on iOS
@available(iOS, unavailable)
class SomeTests: XCTestCase {
    func testSomething() {
        print("operatingSystemVersion=\(ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersion)")
        XCTFail()
    }
}
```

```
// Still runs on iOS
class SomeTests: XCTestCase {
    @available(iOS, unavailable)
    func testSomething() {
        print("operatingSystemVersion=\(ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersion)")
        XCTFail()
    }
}
```

I am able to achieve what I want with the below but this isn't really practical for lots of tests, is prone to error, is determined at runtime and the test methods still execute and show as success (which isn't really the case).

```
class SomeTests: XCTestCase {
    func testSomething() {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
           print("operatingSystemVersion=\(ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersion)")
           XCTFail()
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think the preprocessor macro `#if os(...)` can help because it cannot do version checking.

Is there any other way to achieve what I want?  Am I doing something wrong with `@available` (or maybe this is just a bug)?

Comment: I think it might also help if you provided some information on what exactly you want to achieve with the iOS only tests. A non automatic way would be to have multiple build schemes and have the iOS tests disabled in some and enabled in others. The question remains whether deactivating tests by OS makes sense. Depends on the case :)

Comment: Are you sure this is an actual problem? Most likely the test will show up in Xcode, but it won't actually run when you execute the tests.

Comment: I just checked, this is definitively broken in Xcode 11. Looks like a regression based on previous internet threads

Comment: @JanBrinker I have simplified my example to improve the potential for a good answer.  Full context -> I am writing an SDK/framework for use on both Mac and iOS and tests need to run on both platforms. Certain unit tests will only pass on macOS >= 10.15.1 and iOS >= 12 because of a limitation with JSONDecoder (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59627000) so I'd like certain tests to run on all platforms excluding macOS < 10.15.1 and iOS < 12.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen yes I did check it is actually broken, thats the reason the print statement is there.

Comment: @OliverPearmain file a radar with Apple. Xcode is broken.

Comment: Was a bug ever filed on radar? If so, could you please post a link here. Thanks!

Comment: I have confirmed that this is still broken in Xcode 11.5.

Comment: This appears to still be broken in Xcode 14.0

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by creating a special super class for my iOS13-only tests:

```swift
class iOS13TestCase: XCTestCase {
    
    override func invokeTest() {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            return super.invokeTest()
        } else {
            print("Skipping test because it's iOS13+ only.")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

I then use it in my tests instead of XCTestCase for the iOS13 only tests:

```
@available(iOS 13, *)
class SwiftUITest: iOS13TestCase {
    func test_something() { }
}
```

Xcode still sees the tests, however, their execution is skipped on the version lower than iOS13.

This can be solved much better by bypassing the `XCTestCase.testInvocations` property. Since `NSInvocation` is not available in Swift, it would require implementing the superclass in Objective-C, and I didn't want to do that :)

Answer (score 2):

This might be a good candidate for `XCTSkip`

```swift
class SomeTests: XCTestCase {
    func testSomething() throws {
        guard #available(iOS 13.0, *) else {
           throw XCTSkip("Unsupported iOS version")
        }
        /// Run iOS 13+ tests
    }
}
```

Note that test functions can now be marked `throws`, and this is necessary to use the `XCTSkip` API.